# GCM not receiving registration token

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I started a sample for the latest GCM registration procedure as per the Google documentation. And I'm  facing two very common issues, did look out most probably all the post in stackoverflow regarding both the issues.

1. GCM registration token not received.

As per the documentation, I did:

```
 InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
 String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.arpaul.gcm_udacity.gcmService.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.arpaul.gcm_udacity.gcmService.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Application in Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.arpaul.gcm_udacity.gcmService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".gcmService.ListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".gcmService.GCMInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".gcmService.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Gradle libraries:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
```

Current updated version is 9.6.1 I guess, but whenever I change and sync it shoots

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

All my plugins are upto date
Even added meta  data for google play services but still token not generating.

2. Since the latest GCM procedures include Firebase, its just crashing in my Dell tab having Android version 4.4.

Is there any support library for Firebase which I might be missing out?

I know this is a duplicate question for both the points, but none of the solution worked for me.

Please don't rush to mark this duplicate question or close it, please help me if I'm missing out anything, stuck for 2 days.

Please help..

EDIT:
I missed out the FCM documentation [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=2). It's working via Firebase, even emulator is also receiving GCM message(didn't expect this much). But will try out in my Dell tab now having Android 4.4, it always crashes when I run any app having google-play-service library.

Any hint if I choose to use my server instead of Firebase for the messaging purpose, cause Firebase has some limitation for free use and pricing too for extended too. Any other procedures?

Comment: Can you post which documentation you're following? It's a little bit confusing, the code shows its for GCM, but if you're saying the latest version, you should be using FCM.

Comment: I tried out from this link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

And now I did notice this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=2 is having the library files completely different.Will create another sample I guess, but I don't want to use Firebase, it doesn't work in less that 5.0 i guess, anything on that?

Answer (score 2):

If i see correctly your manifest's permission part is correct. Maybe you have some problem about services and receivers. Here're the receivers and services you should add to your manifest.

How ever i add push notification permissions still.

```
    <!-- Push Notification -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".gcm.MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".gcm.GcmRegistrationService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

And you need to handle receiver's results like below:

Here's your GcmRegistrationService example:

```
public class GcmRegistrationService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "GcmRegistrationService";

    public GcmRegistrationService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            // Send token to your server.
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's your example MyGcmListenerService:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
       // Handle your notification here.
    }
}
```

Here's your MyInstanceIDListenerService example when gets called if your gcm token is refreshed. (Call your registration service again.)

```
public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, GcmRegistrationService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

And finally start service to get token:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, GcmRegistrationService.class);
startService(intent);
```

I hope this'll help you. Good luck.

Comment: I don't find any difference in your code from mine, but I did notice I the current https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=2 is using different libraries and manifest files I guess, so in near future you might have problem too. Is this thing working for you now? what did you do in google developer console?

Comment: Previously I used to do:
1. Enable google cloud messaging in developer console 
2. Copy project id as sender id
3. Create a server Key.
4. A Android api key also req.

But this steps doesn't need sender id and i did create a android api key but didnt work.

Comment: What did you do in google developer console?
Only these or anything else?
1. Enable google cloud messaging in developer console 2. Copy project id as sender id 3. Create a server Key. 4. A Android api key also req.

Comment: yes i did same. but i recommand you to use my code because sometimes little code pieces can be missed. as i said my implementation is working in production now.

Comment: Trying it out, anyways any hint for this problem?

Since the latest GCM procedures include Firebase, its just crashing in my Dell tab having Android version 4.4.

Comment: no sorry. i did not try new firebase implementation.

Comment: can you inform me if your problem is solved? I'm interested in about your issue.

Comment: Yeah, messaging works using Firebase, not by the code you provided, its anyway exactly the same what I did, but google documentation says its deprecated now, only FCM is used for messaging. Still having problem using Firebase in version 4.4.